# how to get all weekdays from a date range and duration

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So i have an initialDate, a travelTime and a endDate,
we also have booleans representing the weekdays

lets say we whave the following:

```
initialDate = 06 Jun 2021
travelTime = 13:00 to 18:00
mon = true, tue = false, wed = true, thu: false, fri = false
endDate = initialDate + 1 month
```

i need to get all mondays and wednesday dates between initialDate and endDate

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: i was trying to loop thru the days with this loop `for (const day = initialDate; day <= endDate; day.setDate(day.getDate() + 7)) {
        mondaysArr.push(new Date(day));
      }` but then realized starting day will not always be monday so i cant loop with the + 7 method

Answer (score 0):

In this code bellow, using momentjs, I create two array, one for Mondays and one for Wednesdays formatted like you wrote the date in your question.

```js
const dateFormatTemplate = 'DD MMM YYYY';

const initialDate = moment('06 Jun 2021', dateFormatTemplate);
const endDate = moment(initialDate).add(1, 'month');

const MONDAY = 1; // moment().day() return a value from 0 to 6(Sunday-to-Saturday)
const WEDNESDAY = 3;

const mondayArray = [];
const wednesdayArray = [];

while (initialDate.isSameOrBefore(endDate)) {
  if (initialDate.day() === MONDAY) mondayArray.push(initialDate.format(dateFormatTemplate));
  else if (initialDate.day() === WEDNESDAY) wednesdayArray.push(initialDate.format(dateFormatTemplate));

  initialDate.add(1, 'day');
}

console.log('ALL MONDAY', mondayArray)
console.log('ALL WEDNESDAY', wednesdayArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```